# How do I determine if there's an arithmetic sequence within a list?

Tags: function-construction, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [find subsequences of constant increase](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9631/find-subsequences-of-constant-increase)

Given an arbitrarily long list of integers (let's say they are sorted), how would one determine if any 3 (or more) of those integers make up an arithmetic sequence? (an arithmetic sequence is where the difference between consecutive terms is the same)
Also how would one determine all such sequences in a given list?

For instance, I'd like this function to return

```
In[] = FindArithmSeq[{2,5,6,8,10,12}]
Out[]= {{2,5,8}, {2,6,10}, {6,8,10}, {8,10,12}, {6,8,10,12}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why should it not return eg `{2,5,8}`?

Comment: yep :) forgot that one

Comment: @JohnD and cartonn if it's consecutive then it's much easier!

Comment: actually, it should probably be all elements anyways, I'm changing my result to the answer you suggested below

Comment: So you do or do not want to enforce the *consecutive* criterion?

Comment: No, consecutive should not be forced. I'd like all possible arithmetic sequences.

Comment: keep in mind that for a list of length `len` there are  `Binomial[len, num]` many subsets, and this grows exponentially (see eg `ListLogPlot@Table[Binomial[l, l/2], {l, 3, 15}]`)

Comment: the lists i'm working with are mostly less than 10 elements long, so this should be all right

Comment: I found the original question.  Leonid's answer gives a solution, though the output is not exactly the same as you show.  If you need to split e.g. `{6, 8, 10, 12}` into `{6,8,10}, {8,10,12}, {6,8,10,12}` as you show in your question you may use this function: `ReplaceList[#, {___, x : Repeated[_, {3, Infinity}], ___} :> {x}] &`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard JM's solution there does what the question here asks (Leonid's does not enumerate all individual subsequences, only the longest)

Comment: I tried searching for a similar question before, but I couldn't find that one. Thanks for pointing it out Mr.Wizard. And yes, JM's solution works as well.

Comment: @acl yes, but it also "blows up" very badly on longer lists.  Leonid's method scales *much* better and you can still recover the sequence segments using the function I gave above.  On a list `Union @ RandomInteger[50, 27]` I just tried, J.M.'s code takes more than 16 *thousand* times longer than the combination of Leonid's code and my expansion function.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard right, because JM's (and mine below) enumerate an exponential (see my comment above) number of subsets. However, as cartonn mentions, his/her lists are small enough that that's fine. And if this is possible, I find it so much simpler than Leonid's solution that it's the hands-down winner. I guess my point is, generality is good, but if one solution is a one-liner and the other something that took me 20 minutes to understand (I accept that my brain is small but there must be some others like that),  then the one-liner does have something going for it.

Comment: Too often, a monster answer gets posted here and everything else gets ignored. Well, I hadn't noticed JM's solution, but when I did need to do this, I saw Leonid's answer and came up with my solution faster than I could understand Leonid's. Since in my use case I cannot go over lists of 10-15, this answer is perfectly fine. So overall what I mean is, it's nice that there's a general answer, but let's not go overboard with fully general code that ends up being unreadable. This is doing people who look for answers a disservice.

Comment: @acl ...says he to the king of terse one-liners. :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard haha, OK I guess you have a point there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works for short lists:

```
f[lst_List, len_] := Module[
  {tpls = Subsets[lst, {len}]},
  Pick[
   tpls,
   1 == Length@DeleteDuplicates[Differences[#]] & /@ tpls
   ]
  ]
```

So for instance:

```
list = {2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12};
Sequence @@ # & /@ (f[list, #] & /@ Range[3, Length@list])

(*{{2, 5, 8}, {2, 6, 10}, {6, 8, 10}, {8, 10, 12}, {6, 8, 10, 12}}*)
```

This finds all list of length 3 that make up an arithmetic sequence, then of length 4, up to the `Length@list`; then the `Sequence@@#&` bit is to get rid of empty sets.

Or am I missing something?